# How can I output HTML from a XML file?

Tags: jquery, xml

I am trying to take the contents of 'description' and place it into a div.
Below is the XML that comes from a jQuery ajax call.

```
<media> 
    <entry> 
        <title>Item Name</title> 
        <description>
            <p>First Line<br />
            Second Line</p>
            <p>More Content</p>
        </description> 
        <author>Name</author> 
        <date>2010-07-06</date> 
    </entry> 
</media>
```

I have tried the following, but cannot get it to works. At best it shows up, but without any formatting (FF3). Otherwise a 'WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR' error is shown (Chrome).

```
$.ajax({
    url: xml_url,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: loadItem
});

function loadItem(data) {
    $(data).find('entry').each(function() {
        $(".playing div.description").html($(this).find("description"));
    });
}
```

Is it even possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hey, I think I worked out a solution (I have been working on this for hours with no avail, so asked the question, and then I manage to work it out soon after, typical, lol).

Simply I used load, and it carries all the formating across.

```
$('.playing div.description').load(xml_url + ' description');
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not entirely certain but everytime I have done this in the past it looks more like this:

```
function loadItem(data) {
    $(data.responseXML).find('entry').each(function() {
        var descr = $(this).find('description').val();
        $(".playing div.description").html(descr);
    });
}
```

The key change there (I think) is `.responseXML` and using the value of description rather than the XML node.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But data.responseXML returns back undefined.

Comment: Tried again. Found out that .responseXML is part of the XMLHttpRequest (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). But I get the same problem - no formatting (FF3) and a 'WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR' error is shown (Chrome).

Comment: Have you tried alerting out the value of `descr` or in your code `$(this).find("description")` ? Does the firebug console give you any further errors/info?

Comment: This is not the correct answer, as none of the XML in the question involves attributes on any of the elements. Thus, the `.attr()` call in this answer is not going to fix anything.

Comment: @HurnsMobile There are no errors in firebug. When I alert the descr it says it is an Object. And it works, the content is displayed in FF, but the p tags are not 'working' nor is the br tag. Chrome gives an error.

Comment: @HurnsMobile No problem, I simply changed it to .find("description"), instead of .attr
Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Nathanael Aha! So instead of the string you are getting the object back. Im not sure which but either try `.find("description").html()` or `.find("description").val()` and I think you will have it fixed.

Comment: .val() returns an empty string, and .html() gives an error.
Don't worry, I will use the .load() function instead (with a HTML output), as it is working.
Thanks.